# Future for geospatial on App Engine?

Tags: spatial-database, geojson, database

2 years ago, this question was posted here at [Gillies's blog](http://sgillies.net/blog/899/future-for-geospatial-on-app-engine/),  on date of 2009-05-15.

Future for geospatial on App Engine?

At that time there was no news relating to any apps of GIS web services using Datastore (Google's App Engine).

Is there any new information on GIS and App Engine over last 2 years?

In particular, I am looking for a WFS that uses Datastore on the backend and a browser and a javascript API on the client that will allow people around the world to collaboratively make maps, which can be represented in structured way such as with geoJSON or a shapefiles.

In general, what cool map making and spatial querying web services use Google's App Engine Datastore instead of typical relational database ?

Comment: you've seen fusion tables, right?

Comment: Unfortunately most of the geospatial python libraries rely on GEOS and other C++ DLLs - none of which are currently supported on App Engine.

Comment: Geospatial queries in datastore are now on alpha stage in Java: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch

Answer (score 4):

Some prelim research:

Proximity and bounding box queries at [GeoModel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/). 
[Good article here.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geospatial.html)

Areal queries at [GISCloud](http://code.google.com/p/giscloud/)

WFS-T at [GeoDatastore](http://code.google.com/p/geodatastore/wiki/HowItWorks)

Answer (score 3):

Since [App Engine 1.7.0 SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) GeoPoints are advertised as supporting [indexed spatial searching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches).  As far as I can tell this removes the need to use an addon like GeoModel.